# Isn't Array name a constant pointer, which can't be used in pointer arithmetic, so why does this program work?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char

The following C program gives me output as `b` but since Array name silently "decays" into a constant pointer so why does the following program work, It should have given an error saying l value required, ie. a variable pointer required for assignment on LHS?

```
void check(){
  char a[10]; 
  a[0] = 'a'; 
  a[1] = 'b'; 
  a[2] = 'c'; 
  f(a);
} 

void f(char a[]){
  a++; 
  printf("%c",*a);
}
```

Edit :

Now I do the same thing but not in a different function, and I get the error following the updated code.

```
void check(){
  char a[10]; 
  a[0] = 'a'; 
  a[1] = 'b'; 
  a[2] = 'c'; 
 // f(a); 
  a++; 
  printf("%c",*a);
}
```

```
source_file.c: In function ‘check’:
source_file.c:73:4: error: lvalue required as increment operand
   a++;
    ^~
```

Comment: When passing arrays to functions, that array-to-pointer decay is exactly what happens. Arguments declared as `char a[]` is really `char *a`. Note that the pointer *not* constant.

Comment: `a` in `f()` is a local variable. Assigning to it doesn't modify the array in `check()`.

Comment: It's the same as doing `char *b = a;`. You can increment `b`.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly my point the reason why we can do char *b = a and then b++ is because b is not a constant pointer.

Comment: Same reason you can have e.g. `const int a = 10; int b = a; b++;` You copy the value into a new variable, and the new variable isn't constant.

Comment: @PawanNirpal Then what is your question? Passing the array as a function argument is the same as assigning it to the parameter variable.

Comment: You can do `b++` because `b` is a pointer variable. You can't do `a++` because `a` is an array, which is a constant l-value.

Comment: So does it mean that passing array doesn't make it a constant pointer, ah! yes I get it, it means a which is  passed  to the function isn't really an array but a mere pointer, yes it makes sense, thanks a lot, It seems I was  confused over trivial things, My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code

```
void f(char a[]){
  a++; 
  printf("%c",*a);
}
```

`a` is not an array - it's a pointer.  In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are "adjusted" to `T *a` - all three declare `a` as a pointer to `T`, not an array of `T`.

When you called `f` with an array argument:

```
f(a);
```

the *expression* `a` "decayed" from type "10-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", so what `f` actually receives is a pointer, not an array object.  It's exactly equivalent to writing

```
f( &a[0] );
```

In the code

```
void check(){
  char a[10]; 
  a[0] = 'a'; 
  a[1] = 'b'; 
  a[2] = 'c'; 
 // f(a); 
  a++; 
  printf("%c",*a);
}
```

`a` is an *array* expression, not a pointer, and an expression of array type cannot be the operand of `++`.

Comment: Thanks John, I understood it